# How to print next few lines after regex match until another regex match?

Tags: regex, shell, awk

For instance, there is a piece of text

```
[task,line:111] first
                second
[demo,line:222] first
[test,line:333] first
[task,line:444] first
                second
                third
[task,line:555] first
```

I only want the lines with [task] and next lines until another [*] appears. Like below

```
[task,line:111] first
                second
[task,line:444] first
                second
                third
[task,line:555] first
```

How can I use awk or other tool in shell script to acomplish it?
I just know I can use

```
awk '/regex/{print $0>"'$output'"}' $file
```

to get lines with [task] and redirect them to another file.Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
    /^\[/ {                                     # the line starts with "["
        if ($1 ~ /^\[task/) f = 1               # set flag for "[task" line
        else f = 0                              # otherwise reset the flag
    }
    f {print}                                   # if flag is set, print the line
' input_file > output_file
```

Then the output_file will look like:

```
[task,line:111] first
                second
[task,line:444] first
                second
                third
[task,line:555] first
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk 'NF == 2 {isTask = ($1 ~ /^\[task/)} isTask' file

[task,line:111] first
                second
[task,line:444] first
                second
                third
[task,line:555] first
```

Comment: Soory for I didn't describe my intention properly. I have edited my question.

Comment: It just need minor tweak to check for starting text. See my updated answer now.

Comment: That's a clever oneliner checking 2 fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content

```
[task,line:111] first
                second
[demo,line:222] first
[test,line:333] first
[task,line:444] first
                second
                third
[task,line:555] first
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[";ORS=""}/task/{print "[" $0}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
[task,line:111] first
                second
[task,line:444] first
                second
                third
[task,line:555] first
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator (`RS`) is `[` and output row separator (`ORS`) is empty string, i.e. row is thing between `[` and `[`, then for each row which has `task` inside I `print` it with `[` prepended, as ORS is empty string no superfluous newline is added (required newlines are already in row). If you want to know more about `RS` or `ORS` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will study it carefully and it will undoubtedly help me to learn awk. Thanks again.